# Setting session variable in Grails controllers

Tags: grails, session-variables

I'm using `Grails 2.5.1` i'm trying to set session variable in a controller and checking it in another controller but the variable came with `null` value

Here is the controller i set the session variable in :

```
def setSessionForHR() {

        session.isCallingHR='true'

    }
```

in the below controller i check the value  but the value is `null`:

```
println( "check : $session.isCallingHR  ") // here i get null   
 if (session.isCallingHR=='true')
    {
       //do something
     }
```

am i missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: `println( "check : ${session.isCallingHR}  ")` here you should be putting brackets really  why are you using string true and not setting it to be a proper true value  ` session.isCallingHR=true`   and test by `if (session.isCallingHR) { do something`

Comment: @vahid did as you mentioned still getting `null`

Comment: not sure what to tell you sessions do work, maybe it is the is since is and has are special words. Try alternatives session.test='something' then look it up in another controller. Try another version of grails to see if issue goes away. One higher and a few lower i.e 2.4.5

Answer (score 1):

```
def setSessionForHR() 
{

//session.isCallingHR='true'
session["isCallingHR"]='true'

}

------------------------------------------

println(session["isCallingHR"])    
def isCallingHR=session["isCallingHR"]
if (isCallingHR)
{
   //do something
}

-----------------------------------------
```

pls refer following link for more info
http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Servlet%20API/session.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16496827)

Comment: I already correct his mistakes in code.
I just gave the link for more information to understand the session in grails.
And also i gave the link which is offical page of grails.
It is not just some other thrid person blog..